# Making datagridview button cell readonly

Tags: c#

Getting error:

> Cannot convert type 'bool' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn

for line:

```
(DataGridViewButtonColumn)row.Cells["Recall"].ReadOnly = true;
```

Any ideas, please

Comment: a) don't mix up column and cell b) what would a 'read-only button' even mean?? 'Disabled'?

Comment: Yes datagridview button for that row will be disabled.

Comment: Your code is attempting to cast the ReadOnly property of Cells["Recall"] to a DataGridViewButtonColumn then set the column to true. Fix the scope of your cast.

Answer (score 1):

There are hints on how to disable a `DataGridViewButtonCell` or a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525305/disabling-the-button-column-in-the-datagridview) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However I'm not sure how much I like them: A lot of work for little gain, afaics..

First the `DataGridViewButtonCell` is not a real `Button` anyway. It is rendered as a `Button`, but that is really just the visuals.

This is different from any other cell type: In a TextCell there is a real `TextBox` overlayed and for ComboBoxCell or CheckBoxCells likewise real `ComboBox` and real `CheckBox` controls are being shown, which can be grabbed and manipulated in the `EditingControlShowing` event. You can even add event handlers to those controls..

Not so for the ButtonCell. Here you need to code the `CellClick` or `CellContentClick` events and query e.g. the `e.ColumIndex` value to determine the column and usually also the `e.RowIndex` for the cell that was clicked.

So functional disabling will involve this code anyway. Here is an example that uses the `ReadOnly` property, which in itself doesn't do anything in a ButtonCell:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (cell.OwningColumn.CellType == typeof(DataGridViewButtonCell) 
    && cell.ReadOnly) Console.Write("This Cell is Disabled");
}
```

The syntax for setting it is for a sinlge cell or the whole column:

```
   ((DataGridViewButtonCell)dataGridView1[1, 1]).ReadOnly = true;
   dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
```

**Note** that after setting the whole **column** to `ReadOnly` you can't set a **single** `Button` back to `ReadOnly = false` !

---

You can visually indicate the disabled state by setting the `ForeColor`:

For one Cell:

```
((DataGridViewButtonCell) dataGridView1[1, 1]).Style.ForeColor = 
                                               SystemColors.InativeCaption;
```

Or for the whole Column:

```
   ((DataGridViewButtonColumn) dataGridView1.Columns[1]).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor =
                                                         SystemColors.InactiveCaption;
```

For these to work you need to set the Buttons' appearence to `Flat`, e.g.:

```
 ((DataGridViewButtonColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[1]).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {           
     var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;                    
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {    
    dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Recall"].ReadOnly = true;   
    }    
    }
```